# Embed players for several types of video streams

Tags: php

Suppose we've different media file links such as

```
$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.mp4"; //MP4

// could be anything else such as
//$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.flv" //FLV
//$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.asf" //ASF
//$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.avi" //AVI
//$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.rmbv" //RMVB
// so on up to 25 well known extensions
```

Okay since no player support all media extensions so i've been thinking to set

`flv,mp4` to `jwplay` - `asf,avi,wmv,mpg,mpeg` to `media player` - `rmvb,rmv` to `real player` - `mov` to `quick time` ..etc.

So for every and each `$link` there should be `function` will get the link file extension by using `pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);` and show player name.

**Question** : Example of 2 extensions `wmv` and `mp4` how to write `function embed($link)` that can knows the extension of the media file and and show player name.

Like this (but it is not working just for showing what i mean)

```
function embed($link){
$ext = pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//some code here i can not know what should be
//something like this
//if ($ext === 'mp4') {
//$what = 'JW Player';
//} else if($ext === 'wmv') {
//$what = 'Media Player';
//} else {
//$what = 'Unknwon';
//}

return $url;
}


// then at applying it for link
$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.mp4";
echo embed($link); // Output : JW Player

// then at applying it for link2
$link2 = "http://www.my_site.com/test.wmv";
echo embed($link2); // Output : Media Player

// then at applying it for link3
$link3 = "http://www.my_site.com/test.ra";
echo embed($link3); // Output : Unknown
```

so can you please wrote function do such job so i can understand how it does works and apply it for further complex examples ~ thanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the return var to `$what`, like this:

```
function embed($link){
$ext = pathinfo($link, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

//some code here i can not know what should be
//something like this
if ($ext === 'mp4') {
$what = 'JW Player';
} else if($ext === 'wmv') {
$what = 'Media Player';
} else {
$what = 'Unknwon';
}

return $what;
}
```

Now it returns the player name.
Then when you call it like this...

```
$link = "http://www.my_site.com/test.mp4";
echo embed($link);
```

...it outputs JW Player.